# Chart.Js and Callbacks in Blazor, are they possible?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, chart.js, blazor

I am using Chart.JS in a Blazor project and seem to have run into a limitation, there seems to be no obvious way to pass a callback, for example a callback for the tick to modify the tick text displayed:

```
Scales = new
{
    y = new
    {
        ticks = new
        {
            color = "white",
            callback = How do I pass a calback here??
        },
    }
},
```

Any ideas on how to accomplish this in Blazor?

Comment: Hi, I think you need check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-7.0) to know how to call js function in blazor app.

Comment: Did you solve this? It would be really cool if you came back to answer your own question if you did.